# Angular lazy tree

Tags: angularjs

I'm studying angular and trying to write treeview with dynamic load. It has some initial pre-loaded nodes, but many of them have to be loaded by demand.
I write initial tree view here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wince/gbbfwzuz/) but cannot understand how to implement lazy load.

- when I click NodeLazy I want to update treeService.Nodes and this update have to refresh view
- when I click any Node I want select this node by bold font and be able get selected from treeService

Sure, I could use one of existing angular tree, but I want to understand how to do this.

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.directive("treeView", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      t: "=src"
    },
    template: "<ul class='ul-node'><tree-branch ng-repeat='c in t.children' src='c'></tree-branch></ul>"
  };
});

app.directive("treeBranch", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      b: "=src"
    },
    template: "<li class='{{b.class_li}}'>{{b.name}}</li>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      var has_children = angular.isArray($scope.b.children);
      $scope.b.class_li = has_children ? "li-node" : "li-leaf";
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var has_children = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
      if (has_children) {
        element.append('<tree-view src="b"></tree-view>');
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }

      element.on("click", function(event) {
        console.log("click|" + scope.b.name);
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (has_children) {
          element.toggleClass("ul-collapsed");
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.service("treeService", function() {
    var nodes = {
    children: [
      { name: "Node_1", 
        children: [ 
            { name: "Node_1.1", 
                children: [{ name: "Leaf_1" }, { name: "Leaf_2" }] },
            { name: "NodeLazy_1.2", }] }, 
        { name: "NodeLazy_2", }]
  };

    return {
    Nodes : nodes   
  };
});

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, treeService) {
    $scope.nodes = treeService.Nodes;
});
```